# JavaScript frame brake but page keep refreshing

Tags: javascript, frame, page-refresh

I used to ping my blog in some website and they place something like a frame(plugin) on top of my blog when someone visited my blog from the ping website.

I intend to break that frame after 30 seconds and I did. 
But, if I use the code I mentioned below.
My blog will break the frame after 30 seconds but it will also continuously refresh my blog every 30 seconds non stop.

'How can I just break the frame within 30 sec without continuously refreshing my website?'

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 

     function getgoing()
      {
        top.location.replace(self.location);
       }

       if (top.frames.length > 0)
        {
         setTimeout('getgoing()',30000);
         } 

    </script>
```

Sorry for bad English

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to achieve, sorry.

Comment: sorry about that, i used to ping my blog in some site but they put something like frame(plugin) if someone clicks on my link inside the ping site, i wan to break that frame after 30 seconds and i did.but if i use the code i mentioned above

it will break the frame after 30seconds but also will continuously refresh my website every 30seconds

'how can i just break the frame within 30 sec without continuously refreshing my website?'

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the frame refreshing as it seems not to stop refreshing perhaps something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 

        var done = false;   
        function getgoing() {
            if(done == false){      
              top.location.replace(self.location);
              done = true;
            }
        }

        if (top.frames.length > 0) {
           setTimeout('getgoing()',30000);
        } 

        </script>
```

Comment: thx for answering.. i tried. it will remove the frame after 30sec but my page will still keep refreshing every 30 seconds in future.. this will bothers my readers..

Comment: yep I can see the problem done will always be false cos the page is reloading - I think the answer below is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'> 

if (top.location != self.location) top.location.replace(self.location); 

</script>
```

if she use code like this, it will remove the frame but i think she want use one code to remove that frame after a few second, if she use the code she mention, it will remove the frame but her blog will refresh in 30 second.